# Reuse a UICollectionViewCell in multiple UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do something similar to this where A, B and C are all different `UICollectionViewController`. My current approach is manually duplicating the cell in storyboard to all different UICollectionViews but have they all have same custom subclass. However, it's not DRY for UI development and I have to manually change replicate the changes in each UICollectionViewCell copy.

I know XIBs can be used to achieve this, but I'm stuck at how to link it with all `UICollectionViewController` through storyboard or minimal Swift code.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Okay, If I use XIB to create a UICollectionViewCell, how can I link it with multiple existing UICollectionViewControllers that exist on the storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anushik use below steps to create custom cell using xib and reuse

1.Create UICollectionViewCell subclass along with xib

2.Add reuse identifier to the cell

3.Register the nib using [register(nib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register) method in viewDidLoad method in UIViewController class

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

4.Use the custom cell in [cellForItemAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview) method of UICollectionViewDatasource

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(item: item)
    return cell
}
```